# How do I get the Wifi IP address on Ubuntu touch

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to get the IP-address of the wireless connection on a mobile device with Ubuntu touch even when it's not connected via USB?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no hardware to test that system.

But you should find that in the Settings. If not, you should somehow be able to open a terminal and type `ifconfig`.

Comment: I don't own either, but how about dragging down then network icon from status bar? You may view the touch video.

Comment: If you have access to the router then see it in the DHCP list of clients

Comment: Can you tell me why you downvoted my answer? You talk about the wifi ip address, and my answer: If you scan your network with nmap or angry ip scanner you will for sure get the IP...

Answer (score -1):

you can connect your device to pc throught with USB.

you can read [this website][https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#SshAccess], a paragraph about **Accessing the devcie over ssh**

Answer (score -1):

An easy way is to scan your network with nmap...

First of all:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Depending on your network ip and subnet setup use nmap to scan:

```
sudo nmap -sP 10.0.0.0/24
```

The above will scan all ip's from 10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.255

**edit:**
If you like GUI's you can also install zenmap

Comment: The question is, how to get the ip address **"on a mobile device with Ubuntu touch"** At this stage I cannot run a shell on Ubuntu touch therefore I thought there are some other ways that I had overseen.

Comment: @NilsB
I guess i was not clear enough: I wasn't thinking about installing anything on Ubuntu Touch. All i was proposing was to use nmap to scan the network from a PC running Ubuntu Desktop. Then connect to the same machine as the Ubuntu Touch device and scan the network. That way you will probably get to know the ip of the Ubuntu touch device.

Comment: maybe unclear from my side. When I am connected with my Ubutu Touch device wirelessly I might not even have a pc available to run nmap.

Comment: No, but you could try while you can...